# Find Deadlock details happened one day ago in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

One user reported a deadlock error in one SQL Server box (he may found it in some application logs).  Anyway, I need to find out details for this deadlock but I never enabled any trace flag like 1204 and 1222.  Does SQL Server log deadlock by default?  Can I find the details about that deadlock somewhere or do I have to enable trace flag and then wait for deadlock happening again?

Comment: It's SQL Server2008 R2.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422986/sql-query-to-get-the-deadlocks-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Yes, using "default extended events trace":

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10644/deadlock-error-isnt-returning-the-deadlock-sql/10646#10646

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this sql to get all the deadlocks.

```
DECLARE @xml XML

SELECT @xml = target_data
FROM   sys.dm_xe_session_targets
JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions
ON event_session_address = address
WHERE  name = 'system_health' AND target_name = 'ring_buffer'

SELECT CAST(XEventData.XEvent.value('(data/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS XML)
FROM   (SELECT @xml AS TargetData) AS Data
CROSS APPLY TargetData.nodes ('RingBufferTarget/event[@name="xml_deadlock_report"]') AS XEventData (XEvent)
```

Comment: It's recoded by SQL Server by defaul and this sql can be executed in any databases since it's server level.