# SQL deadlock information is not available

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, deadlock

I am working on retrieving deadlock information from my sql server. I have also set the trace flag 1222 for this purpose. How ever when the deadlock occurs I could not see the error log in sql server error log. 
To set the trace flag I have given it as a startup parameter for my instance.
Any help would be appreciated. 
The sql server version as returned by  `select serverproperty('productversion')` is 10.50.1600.1
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure how you put it in your startup parameters, but have you restarted the SQL services?  I would enable it immediately by running the following command, DBCC TRACEON(1222,-1)

Comment: @John yes, I have restarted the services too. `dbcc tracestatus` shows that the flag 1222 is enabled globally.

Comment: hmmm... 2 things left.  Are you sure you are getting deadlocks? If so, Are you sure you are on the right server that is returning deadlocks? I've never seen such a behavior.  Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422986/sql-query-to-get-the-deadlocks-in-sql-server-2008