# How to View Deadlock Transactions In SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In our production server, the deadlock happening frequently. Is anyone can help on how to view those transactions from which the deadlock occur?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720508/help-with-deadlock-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this query

```
SELECT db.name                  DBName,
       tl.request_session_id,
       wt.blocking_session_id,
       Object_name(p.OBJECT_ID) BlockedObjectName,
       tl.resource_type,
       h1.TEXT                  AS RequestingText,
       h2.TEXT                  AS BlockingTest,
       tl.request_mode
FROM   sys.dm_tran_locks AS tl
       INNER JOIN sys.databases db
               ON db.database_id = tl.resource_database_id
       INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks AS wt
               ON tl.lock_owner_address = wt.resource_address
       INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p
               ON p.hobt_id = tl.resource_associated_entity_id
       INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec1
               ON ec1.session_id = tl.request_session_id
       INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec2
               ON ec2.session_id = wt.blocking_session_id
       CROSS APPLY sys.Dm_exec_sql_text(ec1.most_recent_sql_handle) AS h1
       CROSS APPLY sys.Dm_exec_sql_text(ec2.most_recent_sql_handle) AS h2
```

Source : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/10/06/sql-server-quickest-way-to-identify-blocking-query-and-resolution-dirty-solution/

Comment: Is there any manual solution to prevent deadlock transactions?

Comment: I'm afraid I have to disagree with this answer (and thus the downvote - sorry!). The query that you have deals with blocking, whereas the OP asked about deadlocks. You can't query about deadlocks out of a DMV because, by definition, one of the processes gets killed and is thus no longer available in the system.

Answer (score 2):

I get using these three methods:

Get active deadlocks:

```
SELECT
    SESSION_ID
    ,BLOCKING_SESSION_ID
FROM SYS.DM_EXEC_REQUESTS
WHERE BLOCKING_SESSION_ID != 0
```

Get text of the query (And check if it is really important):

```
exec sp_whoisactive |session_id|
```

Kill the deadlock (Use wisely):

```
kill |session_id|
```

Also, the previous answer didn't work fine (I don't know why), I've executed this:

Query 1:

```
begin tran
create table ##a (i int)
insert ##a values (1)
```

Query 2:

```
delete ##a
```

Query 3: The answer