# SQL DeadLock in application

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, deadlock

We have MS SQL server.

We have an application where we are getting sql deadlock exception,
we tried to reproduce the issue with "load testing" but we couldn't.

It happens with actual Production scenario

The exception Error is:

> SqlException Transaction (Process ID 658) was deadlocked on lock |
>   communication buffer resources with another process and has been
>   chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Is there any way to find the exact root cause for the issue.??

Comment: There are a couple of options here. http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/capturing-deadlock-information/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720508/help-with-deadlock-in-sql-server-2008?rq=1